# Multiple inputs, multiple outputs; solving when you have simple linear models

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-programming

I am working on a mathematical problem related to a steady state controls problem, and I think this might be the place to ask this.  I've figured out some of the simple cases, and am wondering where might the best place to look for a more generic solution, since the real problem involves more inputs (over 50; this is a problem for multiple light sources and sensors, but could be applied to multi-zone heating ovens, for example).

The problem is simplified, since the outputs are linearly dependent on the inputs.

**For a single input, and three outputs**; say, a single light illuminating 3 sensors:

[image]

I've been able to write out the following; the coefficients are based on geometry, and are fixed.

y1=a*x1+b

y2=c*x1+d

y3=e*x1+f

The goal is to have the values y1, y2, and y3 set to some specific outputs (ya, yb, and yc; in our case the same values, but I solved the generic case).

If we create a objective function F=(ya-y1)^2+(yb-y2)^2+(yc-y3)^2, and derive w/r/t x1 and set to zero, I can find a best fit for things:

x1=((a * ya + c * yb + e * yc)-(a * b + c * d + e * f))/(a^2+c^2+e^2)

(For example, for a = 1, b = -3, c = 2, d = -10, e = 5, f = -25, with ya = 10, yb = 11, yc = 12, the objective function (F = 59) is smallest at x1 = 8).

I've checked this result against a spreadsheet solver algorithm, so I think my algebra is correct.

**For a 3 input, 3 output problem**; say, 3 lights illuminating 3 sensors:

[image]

... the equations are:

y1= a0 + a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3

y2= b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3

y3= c0 + c1 * x1 + c2 * x2 + c3 * x3

I actually solved this problem first, but used a spreadsheet solver, where the objective function is still F=(ya-y1)^2+(yb-y2)^2+(yc-y3)^2. Asking the solver to vary y1, y2, and y3, and minimizing F works.

**The more general case(s)**

Where do I look for solving problems where I've got n inputs, and m outputs, when the relations are linear?  Is a spreadsheet solver still going to cut it?  It kind of bothers me that it is a bit of black magic which I'm not clear how it solves it.

When inputs are less than outputs (like the first problem), solving algebraically for larger values of n seems unwieldy.  I've looked at the two input, 4 output problem, and have tentatively solved it, but you start to turn your paper sideways when deriving for more inputs.  This problem has a lot more inputs and outputs (we'll be looking at as many sensors), so unless I'm mistaken, algebra is out.

I'm thinking this is *somewhat* related to curve fitting of the multiple linear input problem, where you have y = a0 + a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3 + ..., and are trying to find the coefficients a0, a1, a2 etc, given a bunch of data.

In this case, we know the coefficients, but want to set the outputs, but am not quite sure where to go next.  I've used Nelder-Mead (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) in the past for solving nonlinear 2D problems; would this be a solution, perhaps?  Are there any open-source solvers/libraries in Python that might help here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

As far as I understood, it seems that your problem can be represented as

$$
E(x) = ||A x+b-y_0||
$$

or

$$
E^2(x) = x^t A^t A x +2(b-y_0)A x + ||b-y_0||^2
$$

with minimum at

$$
A^tA x_0+A^t(b-y_0) = 0
$$

with

$$
x_0 = -(A^t A)^{-1}A^t(b-y_0)
$$

Here

$b = (a_0,b_0,\cdots, n_0)$ and $y_0 = (y_a, y_b,\cdots, y_n)$

The linear modeling can give strange solutions. For example, in case of $x$ associated to light sources the solution can give darkening properties to some sources... ($ x < 0$)